# How to create a 2D array as rewrite code for the array.reshape() method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, reshape

I'm trying to create function of converting array B to array of other shape in equal q-ty of elements.

```
B = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 10]])
```

to `array([[2, 4],[6, 4],[8, 10]])`

```
def my_reshape (A, m, n):
    A_ravel = A.ravel()
    A_list = [i for i in A_ravel]
    print(A_list)
    print(len(A_list))

    if m*n == len(A_list):
        for elem in A_list:
            A_shape = [[elem for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]                    
    else:
        print('Q-ty', m*n, ' - doesn't match to q-ty of list)
        A_shape = []

    return np.array(A_shape)
```

But it takes only the last element = 10, instead of each of list?

```
OUT: 
[2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 10]
array([[10, 10],
       [10, 10],
       [10, 10]])
```

It has to be

```
    array([[2, 4],
           [6, 4],
           [8, 10]]
```

2 way

```
def my_reshape2 (A, m, n):

    for elem in A_list:

        array= []
        for j in range(m):
        temp=[]
            for i in range(n):
                temp.append(i)
        array.append(temp)

    return array

OUT: [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

How I have to code for taking elements in A to new array?

Comment: What's wrong with just `B.reshape(3, 2)`? If you need a new buffer, `B.reshape(3, 2).copy()` or `B.copy().reshape(3, 2)`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! On my python course I have a special task do not use method array.reshape(), for understanding some modules: function, loops, arrays. Other words, to create a function of converting without reshape().

Comment: I've posted an answer that specifically avoids `reshape`.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer to remove your question from the unanswered queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate the effect of `reshape`, you can make a copy of the data into another array of the correct shape:

```
B = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 10]])
output = np.empty((3, 2), dtype=B.dtype)
output.ravel()[:] = B.ravel()[:]
```

Since `ravel` pretty much always returns a view for simple (contiguous) arrays, the result is as expected:

```
>>> output
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [99]: B = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 10]])                                                         
In [100]: B                                                                                            
Out[100]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  8, 10]])
```

target:

```
In [101]: np.array([[2, 4],[6, 4],[8, 10]])                                                            
Out[101]: 
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

simple reshape:

```
In [102]: B.reshape(3,2)                                                                               
Out[102]: 
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

`reshape` says it essentially ravels the array, and then makes a new one with the new shape:

```
In [103]: B.ravel()                                                                                    
Out[103]: array([ 2,  4,  6,  4,  8, 10])
```

Your target keeps the `ravelled` elements in the same order.  There's no need to do any rearranging.

Doing the same thing with lists is more work.

Nested lists have an easy transpose like operation:

```
In [104]: B.tolist()                                                                                   
Out[104]: [[2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 10]]
In [105]: list(zip(*B.tolist()))                                                                       
Out[105]: [(2, 4), (4, 8), (6, 10)]
In [106]: B.T                                                                                          
Out[106]: 
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 4,  8],
       [ 6, 10]])
```

but you don't want that.

The fast way to get your `A_list` is

```
In [107]: B.ravel().tolist()                                                                           
Out[107]: [2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 10]
```

and one way of collecting 3 lists of 2 from that is:

```
In [112]: B_list = B.ravel().tolist()                                                                  
In [113]: [[i,j] for i,j in zip(B_list[::2], B_list[1::2])]                                            
Out[113]: [[2, 4], [6, 4], [8, 10]]
```